# What the sentence means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, traditional-characters

余憶童稚時，能張目對日，明察秋毫。見藐小微物，必細察其紋理，故時有物外之趣。………一日，見二蟲鬥草間，觀之，興正濃，忽有龐然大物，拔山倒樹而來，蓋一癩蝦蟆也。舌一吐而二蟲盡為所吞。余年幼，方出神，不覺呀然驚恐。神定，捉蝦蟆，鞭數十，驅之別院。

What I thinking is about, there it's a frog that ate the bugs. And somebody pick it to another place. Where the words come from a Chinese textbook in junior high school in Taiwan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in quasi-Classical Chinese and taken from [浮生六记](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Records_of_a_Floating_Life).

Why not browse the [translation](https://archive.org/details/fushengliujisixc0000shen) by Lin Yutang?

Comment: "捉蝦蟆，鞭數十"  is funny.